# Show PHP object data inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootbox

I know there have been just too many questions so far asking about PHP and JS working together...I went through them, but I cannot find an elegant solution for my use case.

What I currently have is following PHP code in my webpage that fetches product info and shows it:

```
<?php
  $p= new Product($prodId);
  $p->getProductInfo();

  //now show product info...
  echo "<div>Product Name: ".$p['productName']."</div>";
  echo "<div>Product Rating: ".$p['productRating']."</div>";
  //etc...
?>
```

Now what I have been asked to do is instead of showing this data directly in the page, I should show it only when a button is clicked. And I should show it inside a [bootbox modal dialog box](http://bootboxjs.com/)

So I did:

```
<span id='prod-details'> View Product Details </span>
<input type='hidden' id ='prod-id' value='<?php echo $p['productId'];?>'>
```

And in my jquery file I have:

```
$('#prod-details').click(function(
   var prodId = $('#prod-id').val();
   productDetail = "Product Details for "+prodId;

   //how do I get rest of product details from PHP object?

   bootbox.alert(productDetail);
));
```

Any help is very much appreciated...I have been trying hard to make this work.

Comment: You need the details to be input type ?

Comment: @frz3993 not sure what you mean...

Comment: Nevermind. Your question `//how do I get rest of product details from PHP object?`, use ajax perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

What I normally do is echo the information inside the bootbox modal div and just hide/show the bootbox modal div with an onClick function

Comment: Agree with that. If we're talking about a small amount of data the user will most probably need, that's probably the best solution. If we're talking about a larger set of data all to be displayed with the same template, it would be helpfull to use some kind of template and data-bind it, and depending on requirements maybe even fetch this data bits by bits through AJAX

Answer (score 0):

you can either put it in your html file like this:

```
<script>
    var productName = <?php echo $p['productName'];?>;
</script>
```

or exactly like you did with the product id, just put all the data you need inside the input div (or any oher div releated to that product)

```
<input type='hidden' id ='prod-id' value='<?php echo $p['productId'];?>' productName='<?php echo $p['productName'];?>'>
```

and then using jquery get that data like you got the id

```
var prodName = $('#prod-id').attr('productName');
```